# System registry for python

Tags: python

I got this code from Stack overflow but when I try to execute the command I get an error. The code and the error is given below. I would be grateful if someone could help:

```
import sys

from _winreg import *

# tweak as necessary
version = sys.version[:3]
installpath = sys.prefix

regpath = "SOFTWARE\\Python\\Pythoncore\\%s\\" % (version)
installkey = "InstallPath"
pythonkey = "PythonPath"
pythonpath = "%s;%s\\Lib\\;%s\\DLLs\\" % (
    installpath, installpath, installpath
)

def RegisterPy():
    try:
        reg = OpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, regpath)
    except EnvironmentError as e:
        try:
            reg = CreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, regpath)
            SetValue(reg, installkey, REG_SZ, installpath)
            SetValue(reg, pythonkey, REG_SZ, pythonpath)
            CloseKey(reg)
        except:
            print ("*** Unable to register!")
            return
        print ("--- Python", version, "is now registered!")
        return
    if (QueryValue(reg, installkey) == installpath and
        QueryValue(reg, pythonkey) == pythonpath):
        CloseKey(reg)
        print ("=== Python", version, "is already registered!")
        return
    CloseKey(reg)
    print ("*** Unable to register!")
    print ("*** You probably have another Python installation!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    RegisterPy()
```

I get the following error:

```
from __winreg import *
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-35-f6f8c1a0ffdd>", line 1, in <module>
    from __winreg import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__winreg'
```

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__winreg'` it is a really self explanatory error.  Can you make us understand what you don't understand about this error ?

Answer (score 0):

As the [Python 2 documentation for _winreg](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/_winreg.html) states,

> The _winreg module has been renamed to winreg in Python 3. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

Check your version of Python. If it is Python 3, as it seems, rename the module references to `winreg` (without the underscore). Look at the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/winreg.html).